# json(p), solr, jquery 1.5.2, 'not called'?

Tags: jquery, ajax, solr

I have an instance of a snapshot of Apache Solr 4.0 running. Solr, for any who do not know, provides an HTTP endpoint that performs queries. You can ask it to return results as json or jsonp (or other things that aren't relevant).

Using jquery 1.5.2, I tried to use `$.ajax` to talk to this, using code from the ajax-solr project on github. The author thereof set things up for jsonp to allow things to work cross-domain.

When you ask solr for jsonp, it really does jsonp. It does wrap the json in the function call.

In that (jsonp) mode of operation, I could not get it to work with either Chrome or Firefox 4. I did some debugging into jquery, but I may have followed a trail of red herrings.

The triggering problem seemed to be that solr returns a content type of 'text' instead of 'application/json'. This, in turn, triggers some complex code in jquery that tries multiple conversion strategies.

In Chrome, the ILLEGAL SYNTAX throw seems to occur when the whole lump is appended to a DOM script node. In Firefox, there's no obvious error, but the jsonp function never gets called.

When I change things to use plain json instead of jsonp, it all works fine (I have solr running in the same host:port as the static content that talks to it.)

I've pasted the giant lump of jsonp and linked it below. It's syntactically valid. Mystified, I am, but not stuck, since, for my application, using plain json works fine.

Answerers point out that the text included chars that are invalid in jsonp because they are invalid in javascript as an explanation for the jsonp failure.

Code to talk to solr:

```
var url = this.solrUrl + servlet + '?' + this.store.string() + '&wt=json&json.wrf=?';
jQuery.ajax({
          url: url,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) { 
                self.handleResponse(data); 
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
          }
        });
```

This comes to the error function with errorThrown:

errorThrown: "jQuery15205321112349629402_1304645690480 was not called"

The response looks like a function call to that lovely item.

The Chrome console says, 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL'.

I captured the full load of javascript, and fed it to jsLint, which has no complaints.

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/ft5rw6uT

I'm going to try to go catch the parsing exception in chrome.

Here's where jquery get the throw:

```
     // Evalulates a script in a global context
    globalEval: function( data ) {
    if ( data && rnotwhite.test(data) ) {
        // Inspired by code by Andrea Giammarchi
        // http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2007/08/global-scope-evaluation-and-dom.html
        var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0] || document.documentElement,
            script = document.createElement( "script" );

        if ( jQuery.support.scriptEval() ) {
            script.appendChild( document.createTextNode( data ) );
        } else {
            script.text = data;
        }

        // Use insertBefore instead of appendChild to circumvent an IE6 bug.
        // This arises when a base node is used (#2709).
        head.insertBefore( script, head.firstChild );
        //Chrome annotates the above with:
        //jquery-1.5.2.js:593Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
        head.removeChild( script );
    }
}
```

And here's a version acquired with CURL, using a shorter string for the function name.

http://pastebin.com/zB6BkmEL

Comment: include response, it will be helpful to troubleshoot further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mkoryak is correct in his reply.  Your solr server needs to wrap the response in the method created by jsonp call.  It looks like you took his advice and now you're on to something new.

The error you're seeing in Chrome:

> 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL'.

is a result of some unicode characters not being correctly interpreted in the json parser.  You should file a bug report with the Chrome guys for this.  In the meantime strip out the unicode characters like "\342\200\251\" (paragraph breaks) and you'll be in business.

edit:  Looks like the Chrome guys are on top of it already:  http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=616 
So TIL: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.12.1.1 - Newlines are not allowed inside JSON strings.  Perhaps we can get the Chrome guys to give us better error handling.

Comment: Solr IS wrapping the response in the method created by the json call.

Comment: Explain, then, why it all works fine without jsonp. If I put it all into plain json mode, the very same text, paragraphs and all, comes over the wire and Chrome eats it. The paragraph break char is not, in any case, a 'control' char like a new line or a form feed.

Comment: Perhaps read this bug report and the follow up reply.  http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82188.  After you get a callback, for a JSONp call, the client executes the JSONp callback method which breaks because the characters U+2028 and U+2029 are line terminators. This means that these characters cannot occur unescaped inside a JavaScript string literal.

Comment: Ran out of characters, continuing.  A regular JSON call does not execute this callback method, so it works.

Comment: Magnus just wrote a nice blog post, summarizing this discussion: http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset

Comment: I believe you, I just wish I could explain why the 'throw' in Chrome was attributed to a line in jquery that inserted the text into a DOM note. maybe it was a &lt;script&gt; element?

Comment: Send the line number over, I'll have a look at it.  I'm guessing that the error is occurring when you attempt to assign that nicely parsed JSON U+202(8|9) character to a javascript string.  FTFA: "JSON is not a subset of JavaScript".  As a fix, on the SOLR side of things, just escape U+2028 to \u2028 and likewise for U+2029.

Comment: Line 593 of 1.5.2. Now that I've done all this reading, I see, I think, that this is a script tag. Meanwhile, I've opened a SOLR bug to ask for the escaping.

Comment: Yes, I think you got it now.  I guess a TL:DR; would be, that the javascript parser doesn't like line terminators in declarations.  Also, can you add a link to your SOLR bug report?

Comment: Nice, looks like they patched it.

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like your callback is not called. 
From the docs:

> The jsonp type appends a query string
>   parameter of callback=? to the URL.
>   The server should prepend the JSON
>   data with the callback name to form a
>   valid JSONP response.

so, does the server handle this properly?

what i mean is, in the case above, the server response should be:

```
Query15205321112349629402_1304645690480({some:json,goes:here});
```

it knows the callback function by looking at the callback param in the query string. Otherwise (from the docs):

> We can specify a parameter name other
>   than callback with the jsonp option to
>   $.ajax().

Comment: Yes, it returns that. Let me pastebuf the response.

Comment: It isn't called because chrome throws an error trying to parse it, first.

Comment: make sure its the actual response, not the browsers interpretation of the response (i am concerned that your json may not be valid)

Comment: I changed the ajax call to expect 'text', and then copied and pasted. However, after I get some sleep, I'll try this with curl and see if something less valid arrives. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: jsonlint.com says you got valid json there.. good luck. please update this when you find the problem, i am curious

Comment: I suspect a charset problem, though there could be a chrome prank. Time to fire up fire fox, as it were.